# TAB не сохраняет выбранную позицию

Tags: tab

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе ТАБа и обновлении страницы, сохранялась выбранной позиции.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Например: я выбираю вкладку "Команды", и при обновлении страницы, он возвращается на вкладку "Обзор", то есть в первой. нужно чтобы при перезагрузке он оставался на выбранной вкладке